# How to write a digitalWrite array for MCP23017 expander chip?

Tags: i2c

I'm using multiple expander chips for my project and I was wondering if there is a way to shorten the loop code by using array? So that I don't have a super long code.

```
void setup() {
  mcp.begin(0);
  mcp1.begin(1);
  mcp.pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  mcp.pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  mcp.pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  mcp.pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  mcp.pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  mcp.pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  mcp.pinMode(6, OUTPUT)
  mcp.pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  mcp1.pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  mcp.digitalWrite(0, LOW); 
  mcp.digitalWrite(1, LOW); 
  mcp.digitalWrite(2, LOW); 
  mcp.digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  mcp.digitalWrite(4, LOW); 
  mcp.digitalWrite(5, LOW); 
  mcp.digitalWrite(6, LOW); 
  mcp.digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  mcp1.digitalWrite(0, LOW); 
  mcp1.digitalWrite(1, LOW); 
  mcp1.digitalWrite(2, LOW); 
  mcp1.digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  mcp1.digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  mcp1.digitalWrite(5, LOW); 
  mcp1.digitalWrite(6, LOW); 
  mcp1.digitalWrite(7, LOW);
}
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Use a variable ( iterator) and count from 0 to 8 (excluding):

```
void setup() 
{
    mcp.begin(0);
    mcp1.begin(1);

    for (uint8 pin = 0; pin  < 8; pin ++)
    {
        mcp .pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
        mcp1.pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop() 
{
    for (uint8 pin = 0; pin < 8; pin++)
    {
        mcp .digitalWrite(pin, LOW); 
        mcp1.digitalWrite(pin, LOW); 
    }
}
```

If the order in which the digital pins are written to LOW matters than split them like in your example, (however, I do not think that is the case).

```
void loop() 
{
    for (uint8 pin = 0; pin < 8; pin++)
    {
        mcp .digitalWrite(pin, LOW); 
    }

    for (pin = 0; pin < 8; pin++)
    {
        mcp1.digitalWrite(pin, LOW); 
    }
}
```

Note : for clarity I would call the mcp variables mcp1 and mcp2 instead of mcp resp mcp2, or an even more intuitive name if there is a clear function for both mcp's.

Using uint8 creates an unsigned byte instead of an int which saves also one byte of stack memory.

Comment: apt. I would also throw the routine in a function so I don't even have to repeat the looping code to apply it...

Comment: @dandavis ... it can be done, personally, I wouldn't do it because it barely reduces the number of lines and makes it less clear, but it's true it reduces copied code. Normally I start refactoring when it is 3 times used OR (2 times and on different locations).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Adafruit MCP23017 library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library) there is a shortcut you can use for setting all the GPIO pins in one go:

```
mcp.writeGPIOAB(val);
```

`val` is a 16-bit value which defines the IO level of all 16 pins at once.

There is a similar function for reading:

```
val = mcp.readGPIOAB();
```

You can also read just one bank of GPIO pins (why they didn't have a similar write function I have no idea):

```
valA = mcp.readGPIO(0);
valB = mcp.readGPIO(1);
```

Unfortunately there aren't any shortcut functions for setting the pin modes.